# Centralized Error Handing with React-native and Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm doing centralized the Error Handing in `react-native`. I'm able to do this just showing the error message whenever error is thrown.

I've created a `ErrorNotification` added to the very top of the component hierarchy of the app.

```
const App = () =>
<ErrorNotification>
    <Login />
</ErrorNotification>
```

//ErrorNotification

```
const ErrorNotification = ({ children, errorCode, errorShow }) => {
return errorShow || errorCode ? <Error {...{errorCode}} /> : children;
};

 function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    errorCode: state.errorReducer.errorCode,
    errorShow: state.errorReducer.errorShow
 };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ErrorNotification);
```

//Error

```
 const Error = ({errorCode }) => {
  const errorMes = getMessageByCode(errorCode)
 return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>{errorMes}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => reuqestedByUser()}>
            <Text>Try again</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

//Login

```
 const Login = () => {
const reuqestedByUser = () => {
    return null;
 };
};
```

My question is... Is there any way to call the `reuqestedByUser()` of Login or any other component function from `Error` screen action.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since `ErrorNotification` is the parent of `Login`, It can pass `reuqestedByUser` to it as props.
Else, You can make use of the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: for demo i just added `Login`. in actual there will be container of all components/screens.